# If condition to check if content in cell is right aligned not working

Tags: vba, excel, alignment, right-align

I have a data that is copied and pasted from a pdf file and then split using 'texttocolumns'. I use this data to extract specific information into another excel. All this is done using vba.

As a part of this, I have the below code to check if contents in cell A12 (example) is right aligned. Although the content in the cell "appears" right aligned, the vba does not show the result as 'True'.

```
If Sheets("Test").Range("A12").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight Then
''Do something
End if
```

Test data

[image: Test data]

Comment: You don't even show A12!

Comment: And what do you mean by not working? It will return True or False

Comment: Data can be indented to the right and not be right aligned btw.  It is a property of the cell you are testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numbers are right aligned by default

so you may want to use this

```
With Sheets("Test").Range("A12")
    If .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight Or (IsNumeric(.Value) And .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral) Then
        MsgBox cell.Value
    End If
End With
```